# Having issues with start and end dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need my output to look like this:
ClientID, Session, Duration, TimeStamp_Start, TimeStamp_End

This is what my query looks like so far:

```
SELECT     ClientID, Session, Duration, MIN(TimeStamp) AS TimeStamp_Start, MAX  
(TimeStamp) AS TimeStamp_End
FROM         dbo.tblHistory
WHERE     (TimeStamp >= DATEADD(yy, - 1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY ClientID, Session, Duration
```

I'm getting this output though.

```
zsw@sdfs  00000020  0     2013-08-13 13:18:58.000  2013-08-13 13:18:58.000
zsw@sdfs  00000020  16112 2013-08-13 17:47:30.000  2013-08-13 17.47.30.000
```

I would like the output to look like this

```
ClientID  Session  Duration  TimeStamp_Start          TimeStamp_End

zsw@sdfs  00000020  16112  2013-08-13 13:18:58.000  2013-08-13 17.47.30.000
```

Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT     ClientID, Session, SUM(Duration), MIN(TimeStamp) AS TimeStamp_Start, MAX  
(TimeStamp) AS TimeStamp_End
FROM         dbo.tblHistory
WHERE     (TimeStamp >= DATEADD(yy, - 1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY ClientID, Session
```